# How do you get displacement at given moment where acceleration is dependent on the displacement?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, spring

[image: Task]

I don't know how to get the time at which the train stops, because acceleration is dependent on the displacement and you can not just simply double integrate the basic equation, all I can do is get to velocity being dependent on the displacement and that is it. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: However you can solve directly for $x(t)$ via $\ddot{x}(t)=\frac{k}{m}x(t)$ (yielding a sinusoid) which can be used assuming that the stopping distance is the full amplitude of the resulting motion and hence time can be calculated

Answer (score 0):

Never solve homework the hard way: Calculate the resonance frequency of the train-spring system:

$$ \omega = \sqrt{\frac k m} $$

The time at which the train stop is independent of the initial velocity: it's just a quarter of a cycle:

$$\Delta t = \frac{\pi}{2\omega}.$$

If you want total displacement, just use conservation of energy:

$$ \frac 1 2 m v^2 = \frac 1 2 k x^2 .$$